# Set affix' data-offset-top in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-template

I'm using Bootstrap and Angular 4 to build a project. I want to use the affix plugin from bootstrap. As my project is going to be a real web-site, hence working at different screen sizes, than the positioning of the menu is going to vary from device to device. In order the affix to be set-up it needs to obtain the exact top position (or "offset") of the element ( in my case a navbar ), and it needs this position plugged in an attribute called data-offset-top.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"
     data-spy="afix" 
     [attr.data-offset-top]="triggerValue" 
     role="navigation">
```

A normal sequence follows - div for the brand name element of the menu, ul-li group for the menu buttons, etc.
I tried to give the data-offset-top a value just after the component's view has been created. This I'm doing through the class of the component calling (I guess) the proper function:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  let triggerValue: number;
    triggerAffixYValue = document.getElementById("main-menu")
                                 .getBoundingClientRect()
                                 .top;
console.log("Offset: " + triggerValue);
```

In the console, as expected I get the output from the function but the effect doesn't trigger. Can you please tell me how I can fix that or if I'm missing anything.

Thank you in advance.